# How to solve ERROR MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS ? (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE BILL

(TRANSACTION_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 

 DATE_BILL DATE, 

 SERVICE_CHARGE NUMBER(10,2) AS (0.10*PRODUCT_PRICE*PRODUCT_QUANTITY) REFERENCES PRODUCT(PRODUCT_PRICE) AND PRODUCT(PRODUCT_QUANTITY), 

 TRANSACTION_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2) AS ((PRODUCT_PRICE*PRODUCT_QUANTITY) + (0.10*PRODUCT_PRICE*PRODUCT_QUANTITY)) REFERENCES PRODUCT(PRODUCT_PRICE) AND PRODUCT(PRODUCT_QUANTITY), 

 TRANSACTION_TYPE VARCHAR2(45), 

 ORDER_ID VARCHAR2(45) REFERENCES ORDERS(ORDER_ID), 

 CUST_ID VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 

 PRIMARY KEY (TRANSACTION_ID)

 USING INDEX  ENABLE

);
```

Comment: I'd say take smaller steps. Create a table with the first column only. Does it work? If it does, create the table with 2 columns. Does it work? Repeat.

Comment: Disclaimer, I'm not an Oracle user, but I have never seen the construct: `REFERENCES PRODUCT(PRODUCT_PRICE) AND PRODUCT(PRODUCT_QUANTITY),`. If you are not certain that it is valid try removing that.

Comment: You were told about most of the errors [when you asked a similar question a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70737956/266304) (deleted, despite being answered, also by Littlefoot).

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that syntax you "invented" doesn't even exist, you're trying to create virtual columns (`service_charge` and `transaction_amount`) that reference columns from another table(s), most probably `product`. Well, you can't.

Looks like you'd rather create a **view**.

Something like this (you didn't post how tables are related to each other so I'm just guessing):

```
CREATE TABLE bill
(
   transaction_id     VARCHAR2 (10) PRIMARY KEY,
   date_bill          DATE,
   transaction_type   VARCHAR2 (45),
   order_id           VARCHAR2 (45) REFERENCES orders (order_id),
   cust_id            VARCHAR2 (45)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_bill_product
AS
   SELECT b.transaction_id,
          b.date_bill,
          b.transaction_type,
          b.order_id,
          b.cust_id,
          --
          0.1 * p.product_price * p.product_quantity AS service_charge,
          1.1 * p.product_price * product_quantity AS transaction_amount
     FROM bill b JOIN product p ON b.transaction_id = p.transaction_id;
```